# Cut both top & bottom of the mesh with knife tool

Tags: mesh, knife-tool

Is there a way to draw the top of the mesh and bottom of the mesh at the same time using knife tool? I would like to draw and cut the same shape at the top and bottom of the mesh.

[image]

Thank you,
W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you see in [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html) , you only `press z` in order to `Cut through`

[image: cut throught]